# How do I have fortran wait for multiple external processes to finish?

Tags: fortran, subprocess, wait, fortran90

I am doing a Monte Carlo simulation, where I use those Monte Carlo sampled points to feed into a potential. Unfortunately, the evaluation of the potential is very slow, and I want to divide up the processes such that say for a 12 core computer, 1 core do the Monte Carlo process, then split the total array into 11 pieces to evaluate the potential for those points in an external program and stitch them back together. However, one challenge I am running into is that when I am waiting for the 11 calculations to finish, they can finish at different times, causing runtime errors on my machines.

So far, I have use the sleep command to have my program wait for the job to finish, but I either to have to give a very long time to sleep or my calculation will run into runtime errors.

split job into parts here
do i = 1,nnode
  split job here
enddo
call system('./external_programoutput &)
...
do i 1=,nnode
   combine results here
enddo
continue with rest of calculation

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We really need to know more details. What kind of threads or processes are they? Which framework do you use? Normally one needs a [mcve] here

Comment: The easiest methods are to use either OpenMP or MPI.  For MPI, I prefer to use OpenMPI.

Comment: I must back up @Steve's comment - these are the tools for this job and it will be a lot easier to learn the basics of them that you need rather than reinvent the wheel.